# C# Overriding method and returning different objects

Tags: c#

I have a virtual method on a base class.  Each time I override it, I want to return different object types.  I know this is not possible, but what would be the best way to handle this situation?

Example of base method:

```
public virtual void clickContinue() 
{
    //click the continue button
}
```

And the method that overrides it:

```
public override myObject clickContinue()
{
    //click then continue button
    //return myObject
}
```

I need to do several similar overrides, all returning different objects.  Again, I know this can't be done the way it's done above - I trying to figure out the best way to handle this situation.

Comment: You could have a base method that returns `object` but you would be better off if your objects implemented a common interface and could return `IMyObjectType`. Or use a generic base class so each subclass can specify `T`. Showing more detail of your object types in the question would help you get a better answer.

Answer (score 7):

> I know this is not possible, but what would be the best way to handle this situation?

If you don't need a default implementation, you can potentially make the class generic, and return the generic type:

```
abstract class YourBase<T>
{
     abstract T ClickContinue();
}

class YourOverride : YourBase<MyObject>
{
     override MyObject ClickContinue()
     {
        //...
```

Comment: This is a great solution if you own the base method. Of course, this wouldn't work if the base method were defined by another library, since you couldn't modify the signature.

Answer (score 0):

I sense an abuse of the override mechanic. The idea behind it is that you do the same thing but with different parameters. The name of the method actually should tell you what it does. So how is it possible the the very same procedure returns `void` (doesn't return anything) and on occasion returns something (non-`void`)?

Are you sure you should not have two completely different methods? This would probably make the API clearer, too.

Otherwise, consider returning always `object`, which happens to always be `null` in case (instead) of the `void` override.

Obviously, the generic way is better for type-safety. Returning `object` means you abandon typing and take over casting manually.